# PHP won't submit list selection

Tags: php

I have been using a mail form successfully until I changed the "state" field from a text field to a select/list.  Now the php will not send the contents of the "state Field."  Do I need to revise the PHP to accommodate the different type of field?  Heres the PHP.

PHP:

```
<?php

  if(isset($_POST['email'])) {         

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED    
    $email_to = "pecraig@moneymovers.com";    
    $email_subject = "OBM/Mailing List Form";         

    function died($error) {    
       // your error code can go here    
       echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";    
       echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";    
       echo $error."<br /><br />";    
       echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";    
       die();    
    }         

    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['email']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['company']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['street']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['city']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['state']) ||    
      !isset($_POST['zip'])) {    
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');   
    }    


    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required    
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required    
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required    
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // required    
    $company = $_POST['company']; // required    
    $street = $_POST['street']; // required    
    $city = $_POST['city']; // required    
    $state = $_POST['state']; // required    
    $zip = $_POST['zip']; // required       

    $error_message = "";

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z0-9 .'-]+$/";

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {    
      $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';   
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {    
      $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }  

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {    
      $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(!preg_match($string_exp,$telephone)) {      
      $error_message .= 'The Telephone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';    
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {    
      died($error_message);    
    }

    $email_message = "This is Response from OBM/Mailing List Page.  If only the first four fields are filled it is a request for an OBM demo - please contact.  If all fileds are filled please contact and enter in database.\n\n";    


    function clean_string($string) {    
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");    
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);    
    }   


    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Street: ".clean_string($street)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "City: ".clean_string($city)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($state)."\n";    
    $email_message .= "Zip: ".clean_string($zip)."\n";        

    // create email headers    
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".    
    headers = 'Cc: info@moneymovers.com'."\r\n";    
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .    
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    header('location: http://moneymovers.com/download.htm');

    ?>

    <!-- include your own success html here -->

    <?php

  }

?>
```

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td width="62" height="12" valign="top" class="text10"><span class="style5">State</span></td>
  <td height="12" valign="top">

    <select name="State" id="State">
      <option selected>AL</option>
      <option>AK</option>
      <option>AZ</option>
      <option>AR</option>
      <option>CA</option>
      <option>CO</option>
      <option>CT</option>
      <option>DE</option>
      <option>D.C.</option>
      <option>FL</option>
      <option>GA</option>
      <option>HI</option>
      <option>ID</option>
      <option>IL</option>
      <option>IN</option>
      <option>IA</option>
      <option>KS</option>
      <option>KY</option>
      <option>LA</option>
      <option>ME</option>
      <option>MD</option>
      <option>MA</option>
      <option>MI</option>
      <option>MN</option>
      <option>MS</option>
      <option>MO</option>
      <option>MT</option>
      <option>NE</option>
      <option>NV</option>
      <option>NH</option>
      <option>NJ</option>
      <option>NM</option>
      <option>NY</option>
      <option>NC</option>
      <option>ND</option>
      <option>OH</option>
      <option>OK</option>
      <option>OR</option>
      <option>PA</option>
      <option>RI</option>
      <option>SC</option>
      <option>SD</option>
      <option>TN</option>
      <option>TX</option>
      <option>UT</option>
      <option>VT</option>
      <option>WA</option>
      <option>WV</option>
      <option>WI</option>
      <option>WY</option>
      <option>AS</option>
      <option>GU</option>
      <option>PR</option>
      <option>VI</option>
    </select>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Could you add the HTML for the `<select>` to the question, please? You shouldn't have to change the PHP code so long as the field is still named the same, so I assume that the error is on the HTML side of things.

Comment: …and always check the return value of the `mail` function (and remove the error suppressing `@`). And why all those white lines?

Comment: This is probably not related to the `select` issue, but there is a problem with how you are building the email headers. Consider using concatination (".") consistently or use `$headers.=` to append.

Comment: I'd also point out that your email validation regex isn't quite right - it's possible to have apostrophes in the address part (`Tom.O'Connor@` for example); and in the domain part, you're checking that the last part is between 2 and 4 characters long. However, there are valid top level domains of both '.travel' and '.museum' (though I don't believe either are very widely used)

Comment: Indeed. It's better to use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) to check for validity.

Comment: andrewsi I added the HTML below the PHP - see edit

Comment: Marcel - I'm new here and can't seem to get how to format my code so it looks like it does in the file.  There are none of the white lines you mention. I'm a graphics guy who's been thrown into the stewpot of coding aaaieee.....

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Try changing the name of your `<select>` list from "State" to "state". Capitalization matters.

I retract my original answer below.
Apparently "If it is not defined, its default value is the text content of the element."
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

**ORIGINAL (obsolete):**

<s>You'll need to give your `<select>` list a `name` and the `<option>` some values:</s>

```
<select name="state">

  <option value="AL" selected>AL</option>
  ...

</select>
```

**EDIT:**

Also, when building email headers, you seem to be mixing concatenation with direct variable definitions.

Try:

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'Cc: info@moneymovers.com'."\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

OR

```
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: info@moneymovers.com'."\r\n";
$headers .=  'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n";
$headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: The values are there - they are just not showing up in the window.

Comment: I didn't realize that "If it is not defined, its default value is the text content of the element." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Took care of the mixing problem - removed $headers = from 'Cc...  works fine.  Thanks